# Program that can listen to a song and find out what it is?

Tags: windows, gratis, music, music-recognition

I am looking for a program similar to [Shazam](http://www.shazam.com/) on mobile, but for Windows 7 that can do exactly what it does on mobile which is:

> Identifying music being played in the surroundings.

Ideally I would like a program that:

- can identify music being played (e.g. "*Believe* by Justin Bieber")
- is free
- does not involve the use of [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)
- is simple and easy and not a pain to configure/use
- runs on Windows 7

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Ahhh, you should chose Metallica as an example instead of Beiber... :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Tunatic](http://www.wildbits.com/tunatic/):

- Identify music being played
- Free
- Simple to use
- Runs on Windows

[image]

Comment: This one worked for me. Otherone kind of did but then didn't at the same time if that makes sense. xD

Comment: **The servers for this app seem to have stopped working.** Post a comment if you manage to get it working.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Audiggle](http://www.audiggle.com/):

- Identify music being played
- Free
- Simple to use
- Runs on Windows and soon on Mac OS X.

[image]

Comment: **The servers for this app seem to have stopped working.** Post a comment if you manage to get it working.