# Software to identify music being played in the sound card output

Tags: music-recognition

I am looking for a software (for PC, not mobile) that is able to identify the music being played/streamed on the computer sound card output, without the need to use a microphone to detect the sound.

Examples:

- Identify a music being played on the browser
- Identify a music being played by an application

Does anyone know any application with such features?

Comment: Which operating system(s)?

Comment: Windows or Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program that can listen to a song and find out what it is?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6792/program-that-can-listen-to-a-song-and-find-out-what-it-is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used My Music Recognition before? It should accomplish what you are trying to do. It is able to take the sound from your sound card, look it up on a music database, and return the song information back to you. The application runs on Windows OS.

## [My Music Recognition](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mymusicrecognition/) (Free)

> My Music Recognition uses a powerful audio recognition engine in order
>   to help you get the name of the song you are listening to. It can
>   capture sound from radio streams, the installed music player or any
>   other source and display the name of the song in seconds.
>
> [image: My Music Recognition on the taskbar]

Comment: It needs you to Register on "The Echo Nest" to get an API key for it to work :(

Comment: And the server is down.

Answer (score 0):

For music playing on the browser, there's a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audd%C2%AE-music-recognition/lhhohkfofnfbnildpdhhjeeenapeceei).

When there's a sound on the current tab, and you click on the extension icon, it starts recording the sound. After a couple of seconds, it sends it to the [Music Recognition API](https://audd.io/) that recognizes the music and shows what the song is currently playing.

If you have music downloaded on your computer, you can open the audio file in the browser and use the extension just the same.

Disclosure: I work at AudD, the creators of the extension.

Comment: It works like magic, thanks , I used it on chrome, on macos